# Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, react-redux, gatsby

I get this error when I run gatsby build. I have not used "document" in my code. Can someone explain what this means?

> ERROR
>
> Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/": {
> "componentChunkName": "component---src-pages-index-js",   "path": "/",
> "result": {
> "pageContext": {}   },   "staticQueryHashes": [] }
>
> failed Building static HTML for pages - 2.990s
>
> ERROR #95312
>
> "document" is not available during server side rendering.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this issue appears is because somewhere in your code you are using `document` global object and, because `gatsby develop` is rendered by the browser, where there are `window` and document global objects, it compiles, however, when you run `gatsby build`, the code is compiled in the Node server, where there's no `window` or `document` variables because they are not even defined yet, they are client-side variables parsed in the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering).

This is an extreme reduction of what's happening, you can find a more detailed explanation in [Debugging HTML Builds docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

To fix/bypass this issue, you only need to add the following condition where you are using `document` object.

```
 if(window !== "undefined"){
   // your document or window manipulation
 }
```

You can use both `window` or `document` in the condition, they are equivalent in terms of bypassing the server-side rendering.

If you are not using `document` in your project, the issue may still rise if some of your dependencies (third-party) are using it (i.e: canvas, maps, sliders that uses JavaScript calculations, etc). If that's your scenario, the way to bypass it is to ignore webpacks bundling by adding a `null` loader:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /bad-module/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Where `/bad-module/` is a regular expression (`test`) (that's why is between slashes, `/`). In this case, you need to replace `bad-module` for the dependency folder name in `node_modules`.

Comment: Thank you, after removing the react_router_dom module, it worked.