# npm run build gatsby: "Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/404/"..."

Tags: build, gatsby, react-three-fiber

When npm building my gatsby project, I get the following:

```
Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/404/": {
  "componentChunkName": "component---src-pages-404-js",
  "path": "/404/",
  "result": {
    "pageContext": {}
  },
  "staticQueryHashes": []
}

failed Building static HTML for pages - 3.357s

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/404/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  21 |     };
  22 |     this.defaultAttributeTypes = {
> 23 |       position: 'Float32Array',
     | ^
  24 |       normal: 'Float32Array',
  25 |       color: 'Float32Array',
  26 |       uv: 'Float32Array'
```

I don't know what it means, by searching the internet, I found this question [Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852052/page-data-from-page-data-json-for-the-failed-page), I learned that this error could be caused by using the window object, so  I tried to check for the window use in my code, the problem was that I use react three fiber, and it may be using this document object,

Then, the same answer showed that one could bypass this error by adding a code to the gatsby-node.js (it doesn't say by I guess), basically exporting onCreateWebpackConfig (in this file I'm exporting sourceNodes and onCreateWebpackConfig, hope this doesn't cause any error)

The problem persists.

I also have a 404 page

```
import React from "react";

const NotFoundPage = () => {
    return <div>Sorry, the page you requested was not found</div>;
};

export default NotFoundPage;
```

Any hints please, I really don't know how to fix it

****** EDIT ******

Ferran asked me for my onCreateWebpackConfig, here it is:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
        actions.setWebpackConfig({
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /react-three-fiber/,
                        use: loaders.null(),
                    },
                ],
            },
        });
    }
};
```

I typed "test: /react-three-fiber/,", but I'm not sure of it, I'm supposed to type the "bad module", I don't know, I only know my components

Comment: Can you share your `onCreateWebpackConfig`?

Comment: I added what you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out when you deal with [third-party modules that use `window`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) or other global objects you need to add a `null` loader to webpack configuration to bypass the server-side compilation using `onCreateWebpackConfig`. In your case, since the package name is [`@react-three/fiber`](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber), try something like:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /@react-three\/fiber/,
          use: loaders.null(),
        },
      ],
    },
  });
};
```

Keep in mind that `test` is a regular expression (that's why is between slashes, `/`) and it matches the folder name under `node_modules`. Be sure that the folder name matches the regular expression.

Answering the duplicity of [configuring gatsby webpack to don't check base objects like window when compiling a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020249/configuring-gatsby-webpack-to-dont-check-base-objects-like-window-when-compilin)

> But I also use `canvas`, `window.innerWidth`, and whatnot, in a component
>
> How do I set another rule to indicate webpack to not throw that error
> when checking a component?

For third-party dependencies you just need to keep adding libraries to the previous `null`-loader configuration:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /@react-three\/fiber/,
          use: loaders.null(),
        },
        {
          test: /other-library/,
          use: loaders.null(),
        },
      ],
    },
  });
};
```

Keeping in mind what I said, `/other-library/` stands for a folder name inside `node_modules`.

For the internal use of `window` object, you just need to add the following condition in before using it:

```
if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
  //your window calculation
}
```

Depending on when and how you are using `window`, you may not need to wrap it in this condition (i.e: if you use `window` in a `useEffect` that is not triggered until the DOM is loaded where window will be always set).

All these approaches can be found at Gatsby docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/

---

> By the way, I'm having two exports in gatsby-node.js:
> `exports.sourceNodes = async ({...` for a data that I use with a
> graphql, and `exports.onCreateWebpackConfig =...` described here,
> is there any problem with that?

Of course not, is just a file exporting functions. It's how it is supposed to work and that's the reason why you have a bunch of APIs available.